# Fast way of getting a specific struct object from an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I have this simple `struct` called `Item`.

```
struct Item {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;

    Item() : id( 0 ), name( std::string( "" ) ) {

    };
};
```

Then I have this class to hold all these `Item`s.

```
class ItemData {
public:
    std::vector< Item > m_Items;
private:
    void load() {
         // Parse a JSON string to fill up m_Items vector with
         // Item objects.
    }

    const Item getItem( unsigned int pID ) {
        // Create an "empty" Item object with ID = 0 and name = ""
        Item temp = Item();

        // Loop through the vector
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Items.size(); i++ ) {
            // Check if the current Item object has the id we are looking for
            if ( m_Items.at( i ).id == pID ) {
                // The item is inside the vector, replace temp with the
                // target vector
                temp = m_Items.at( i );

                // Stop looping
                break;
            }
        }

        // If pID was found, temp will have the values of the object inside the vector
        // If not, temp will have id = 0 and name = ""
        return temp;
    }
};
```

I feel this method takes too much time, especially if `ItemData::getItem(unsigned int)` was invoked inside a loop.

Is there a more efficient way of getting objects inside a vector without looping through the vector? Should I use a different container instead (`std::list` for example)?

Comment: What are some examples of your IDs? Regarding a different container, `std::map` has O(log n) lookup time.

Comment: @DarkFalcon IDs are simply unsigned integers. `0`, `1`, `176`, `2000` are some valid IDs.

Comment: `name( std::string( "" ) )` is entirely redundant.

Comment: `getItem` is gross.  For one thing, you're reinventing the wheel.  `std::find` does this for you, given that you provide a functor (or a lambda in C++11).  For another, `getItem` doesn't just  *get the item*.  It find it, and then it replaces it.  Simple is better than complex.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see. I will take note of that.

Comment: @JohnDibling I wasn't aware of the other STL containers' capabilites until now. The `getItem` comment is also noted. Should it rather be `obtainItem` or something?

Comment: @JohnDibling: What do you mean "it replaces it"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Oops, misread code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over all items in the container, then vector is great. If you do the find relatively infrequently where the linear search doesn't matter performance wise, then the vector is probably still ok.

If you need to be able to look up an item by its id and don't care about preserving the insertion order of the items in the container, then either use `map` or `unordered_map` depending on your sorting needs, container size, etc.

If you need to maintain the insertion order *and* do fast lookups by id *and* you won't be removing items from the vector, then I would suggest an `unordered_map` of id to index, and maintain the id-index mapping when you add new items.

Comment: I would like to retain insertion order as well as fast lookups but removing items would probably be not needed.

Comment: @LanceGray: I suggest a solution based on your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `std::map` instead:

```
class ItemData {
public:
    std::map<unsigned, Item> m_Items;
private:
    void load() {
         // Parse a JSON string to fill up m_Items vector with
         // Item objects.
    }

    const Item getItem(unsigned id) const {
        std::map<unsigned, Item>::const_iterator it = m_Items.find(id);
        if (it != m_Items.end())
            return it->second;
        return Item();
    }
};
```

You could consider `std::unordered_map` as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with `<unsigned, Item>`. I can tell that `unsigned` will be the key for each `Item` object, but shouldn't `unsigned` be `unsigned int`? Or they are of the same type?

Comment: @LanceGray Yes, they are the same.

Comment: This is a good reason to write `unsigned int`. Okay so you saved four keystrokes: well done! You killed clarity as a result, though.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not `std::list`. I believe you're looking for `std::map` (which maps unique IDs to objects). Or perhaps `std::set` (which just stores unique objects) with a custom comparator, so that the `Item`s would be compared based on their `id`.

`set` would have the downside of storing the objects as `const`. I believe `map` suits you best (the overhead of storing the `id` once as the map key and once inside the `Item` is low).

Comment: I wouldn't mind my objects to be `const` as I am most likely not going to alter the container and its objects once they have been set up.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to retain insertion order as well as fast lookups but removing items would probably be not needed

So what you want is to make an index for the vector.  That is create a hash table that maps the item id to the items position in the vector:

```
class ItemData {
    vector< Item > m_Items;
    unordered_map<unsigned int, size_t> m_ItemsIndex;

    void prepare_index()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Items.size(); i++)
           m_ItemsIndex[m_Items[i].id] = i;
    }

    Item& get_item(unsigned int id)
    {
        size_t pos = m_ItemsIndex[id];
        return m_Items[pos];
    }
}
```

This increases the speed of lookup from linear (O(n)) to constant time (O(1)).

Call `prepare_index` at the end of `load`.  You'll also want to add error checking etc, but you get the idea.

Insertion order is preserved because you can still iterate the vector directly.